# Repeat records when using order by rand() in my query

Tags: mysql

Hi I am getting repeat records with this mysql query. Can anybody suggest a query which does not repeat the previous record.

```
SELECT * FROM `photo`, `user` where  photo.userid = user.userid  ORDER BY RAND()  LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: how can it repeat rows if you select only one?

Comment: that is what appears funny it shows one record twice after few records.

Comment: in this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/952ab9/1/0 it doesn't